# SPFX Build Failed with " Cannot find module '@fluentui/react' "

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am trying to build SPFX(React Framework) with Fluent UI. I am not able import any Fluent UI components. VS code failed to build with error : **Cannot find module '@fluentui/react'**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried npm i @fluentui/react-components

Comment: Which version of SPFx / Node.js are you using? Also, try running `npm i @fluentui/react` command before building the web part. Let us know if it works.

Comment: Node JS is 10.24(as per Microsoft recommendation)

Comment: @Saira Yes, It had already done

Answer (score 1):

Please run below cmdlet

```
npm install @fluentui/react
```

And you will get following
[image]

Comment: I had this added already..but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Install "office-ui-fabric-react": "^6.189.2"
and use 'office-ui-fabric-react" instead of '@fluentui/react'

Comment: I need to use Fluent UI.

Comment: Fabric ui is same as fluent ui but an older version

Comment: thats why I dont want to use. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of **SPFx v1.4.1**. Solution generator referenced to older version of packages which not compatible with **FluentUI** (you have to use *office-ui-fabric-core*). Below definitive guide describes it well.

**Definitive Guide:**

https://www.voitanos.io/blog/definitive-guide-sharepoint-framework-sharepoint-server-2019/

**Workaround to use FluentUI  in SPFX 1.4.1:**

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/build-sharepoint-framework-solutions-for-on-premise-sharepoint-server-2019/